# Move other views under Scroll view in storyboard with very limited re-setting / constraints , Swift

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, storyboard, scrollview

I need to add Scroll View to very old code for iOS Swift, if I move other Views under Scroll view, those positions will be changed, since there are quite a few Views there, do i need to re-set and re-constraint all of those? Is there there any better way to minimize those work? since i just want to add Scroll to the current set, big thanks for all hints, tips! [scroll view 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPPnv.png) [Scroll view 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I82CY.png)Also see images

Comment: Tip #1: try to explain as if **we** don't know what you currently have or how you want it to look. Your `scroll view 1` image *appears* to have a scrollview, with NO subviews? It also has "Left View" highlighted, and that *appears* to be what you are showing in your `scroll view 2` image? Doesn't make much sense. However... your 2nd image looks a lot like a typical tableview or collectionview cell. Are you saying you want a scrollabel "list" of the 2nd image views?

Comment: I just want to add a ScrollView here, and all of those Left View, Right View etc will be the subviews of this ScrollView. But when I moved e.g., "Left View" to under Scroll View, it seems that i have to reset all the constraints again, is there any better ways to do that? yes, those that typical tableview, collection view cells. Thanks again!

Comment: It is still very hard to say, based on the images you've posted... It *looks* like you should have no trouble adding `Left View` as a subview of `Scroll View`, so without more information, not sure what to tell you. Is there any reason you don't want to use a Table View or a Collection View?

Comment: Is that(image) all contained in a subview or just set in the viewcontroller view?

Comment: I want to add all the Views to the subviews of the ScrollView.

Comment: I don't have problems to add them to the subviews of the ScrollView, but when I did it, their position are changes, do i need re-set all the constraints again, is there any better way to do that?